# mutate() function in R produces values different from a direct calculation of the same input

Tags: r

I want to modify the "lakers" dataset from the lubridate library, so I have a first code which produces the `chartData`.
After that I need to add 2 calculated columns, and I use the `mutate()` function.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)
library(ggthemes)
library(scales)
library(lubridate)
chartData <-
  lakers %>%
  filter(
    (player != "" & team == "LAL" &
       result == "made" &
       etype %in% c("shot","free throw")
    ) |
    (player != "" &
       team == "LAL" &
       etype == "rebound")
    ) %>%
  mutate(
    rebound = ifelse(etype == "rebound", 1, 0)
  ) %>%
  group_by(game_type, period, player) %>%
  summarize(
    `Total Points` = sum(points),
    Rebounds = sum(rebound)
  ) %>%
  rename(
    `Game Type` = game_type,
    Period = period,
    Player = player
  )
  
graph_data <-
  chartData %>%
  mutate(
    Scaled.Rebounds =
      round(rescale(Rebounds, to = c(-10, 10)), 1)
    ,Scaled.TotalPoints =
      round(rescale(`Total Points`, to = c(-10, 10)), 1)
  )
```

Why if I calculate separately
`round(rescale(chartData$Rebounds, to = c(-10, 10)), 1)`
I obtain a different output from the one which is produced by the `mutate()` function?

Comment: It is probably to do with the grouping. Your `chartData` is grouped, so the mutate function will act on each group separately. Your other version will ignore the grouping.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `mutate` and everything with `group_by`. As the commenter above correctly stated your `chartData` object is still grouped. If you add `ungroup()` at the end of the first expression you will get the same result as in the direct call.....  The behavior you are seeing here is an intended consequence of how dpyr handles grouping i.e. each `summarise` call strips one grouping level. And because you group by three levels and call summarise once the resulting df is still grouped (newer vesions of dplyr even warn you of that fact)